# MS Azure AD connect & Exchange hybrid deployment

Tags: exchange-2010, entra-id, microsoft, exchange-hybrid

I have a MS Small Business Server 2010 server with Exchange. We have looking to migrate to O365.
I deployed a new Windows 2019 server (the SBS machine's UI was painfully slow) and promoted that to the PDC. I then installed MS Azure Active Directory Connect and started syncing the AD. I did not enable Exchange deployment.
Now I am in a better place to begin moving to a hybrid environment with a view to eventually moving mailboxes to Exchange online.

My question is, do I need to install MS AAD on the SBS server where Exchange lives and then enable "Exchange hybrid deployment" or would in work from the PDC?

[MS ADD configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOJNU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with what joeqwerty has replied above, here are detailed Installation prerequisites for AAD:

- Azure AD Connect must be installed on a domain-joined Windows Server
  2016 or later.
- Azure AD Connect can't be installed on Small Business Server or
  Windows Server Essentials before 2019 (Windows Server Essentials 2019
  is supported). The server must be using Windows Server standard or
  better.
- The Azure AD Connect server must have a full GUI installed.
  Installing Azure AD Connect on Windows Server Core isn't supported.
- The Azure AD Connect server must not have PowerShell Transcription
  Group Policy enabled if you use the Azure AD Connect wizard to manage
  Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) configuration. You can
  enable PowerShell transcription if you use the Azure AD Connect
  wizard to manage sync configuration.

For more details: [Installation prerequisites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-prerequisites#installation-prerequisites)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, do I need to install MS AAD on the SBS server where
> Exchange lives and then enable "Exchange hybrid deployment" or would
> in work from the PDC?

You can rerun the Azure AD Connect wizard from the new server and enable Exchange Hybrid. Azure AD Connect does not need to be installed on the SBS server.